# Can I stop the Steam client from crashing each time I shut down my Mac?

Tags: steam, macos

I have the Steam client installed on my Macbook Pro, and each and every time I shut my Mac down without first quitting the Steam client, the client crashes.

While the end result is the same (the client terminates), crashing is a much less elegant affair, and I suppose it could also be potentially harmful. Is there a way to stop this from happening, other than remembering to close the client beforehand? Has anyone else even come across this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue, It's due to a memory leak with the Store. Look at the following link for the fix:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150221071531/http://macformat.techradar.com/blog/steam-for-mac-crashing-try-this-trick

If you change your client's initial page to something other than the store you should be fine. If you need to use the store, I recommend closing the client and restarting before playing.

Comment: While I think it might be worth trying, I am not too sure it the same issue. Considering that the question was asked almost a year ago. It would be interesting to see if OP experiences this problem to this day.

Comment: @theUg Oh it definitely still happens, but not like this article describes. Still, I'll be sure to give the solution a try and report.

Answer (score 1):

Your Steam client might not have crashed at all.

While Steam itself seems a lot more stable today, I believe I remember that happening to the early Mac Steam client versions on my machine, too.

I still experience OS X often considering Steam games crashed when they terminate even though they were gracefully exited using the appropriate in-game button. This effect seems strongest with newly released games, triggering a crash report nearly every time a Steam game is exited, but it seems to wear off as the titles grow older, I can't tell if they are being patched or whether OS X remembers them for acting strangely and stops bothering after a time.

So, maybe there's nothing to worry about but OS X just can't figure it out and worries in vain.

Comment: While it is beyond my capabilities to verify whether or not the crashes I am experiencing are actual crashes, the frequency of this event has greatly declined, which I can only attribute to Steam getting more OSX-ish, as you yourself suspect.